# Mypy complaining about [no-any-return] rule being violated for obvious boolean expression

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

The following code throws a mypy error:

```
from typing import Dict, Any

def asd(x: Dict[str, Any]) -> bool:
    return x['a'] == 1

asd({"x": 2})
```

IMO it doesn't matter what is passed as a dict. `x['a'] == 1` should always be a boolean. But mypy complains with:

```
test.py:4: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "bool"  [no-any-return]
```

Any Idea how to fix is besides peppering our codebase with `# type: ignore[no-any-return]`?

my setup.cfg for reference:

```
namespace_packages = True
explicit_package_bases = True
check_untyped_defs = True
warn_return_any = True
warn_unused_ignores = True
show_error_codes = True
```

Comment: A very famous example of an object that does not return a boolean when compared with `==` is the `numpy.array`. "The truth value of ... is ambiguous"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__eq__` method, one of Python's rich comparison methods, does not *always* return `True` or `False`, it can also return `NotImplemented` (or other values).

This is used, for example, in the case where the first type cannot compare itself with the second, so `a.__eq__(b)` returns `NotImplemented`. In that case, it then tries `b.__eq__(a)` as a fallback <sup>(a)</sup>. If that *also* returns `NotImplemented`, then I believe it falls back to the base `object` type to figure out equality.

You can see the way `mypy` has defined the typing for this in its source code, specifically `mypy/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/_operator.pyi`:

```py
def eq(__a: object, __b: object) -> Any: ...
```

*That's* why you're getting that particular message.

As a quick fix, you can change the function to return `bool(x['x'] == 1)`. This is *exactly* what Python itself does when evaluating the return value in a boolean context, so should be acceptable for placating `mypy` <sup>(b)</sup>.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It's a *little* more complex than that, involving also the hierarchical type relationships of the two items, but the bottom line still stands: rich comparison operators do not always return a `bool`.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> This is covered in the [Python documentation for the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) (my emphasis):

> A rich comparison method may return the singleton `NotImplemented` if it does not implement the operation for a given pair of arguments. By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return ***any*** value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an `if` statement), Python will call `bool()` on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

Interestingly, though this doesn't change the validity of this answer, the section after that states:

> By default, `object` implements `__eq__()` by using `is`, returning `NotImplemented` in the case of a false comparison: `True if x is y else NotImplemented`.

But I'm not convinced that's accurate. In the [actual code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/object.c), both `==` and `!=` seem to result in `True` or `False`, depending on object identity, and never returning `NotImplemented` or raising an exception (the exceptions happen only for ordering comparisons like `<` or `>=`):

```c
/* If neither object implements it, provide a sensible default
   for == and !=, but raise an exception for ordering. */
switch (op) {
    case Py_EQ:
        res = (v == w) ? Py_True : Py_False;
        break;
    case Py_NE:
        res = (v != w) ? Py_True : Py_False;
        break;
    default:
        _PyErr_Format(tstate, PyExc_TypeError, ...
```

As pointed out in a comment, the identity checking is done at a different level to base objects, for example,the [type objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d97aef8ebfbbb275384b17f06945e583fb3189ea/Objects/typeobject.c#L5076). So
I'd take that part of the documentation with a grain of salt :-)

In any case, it shows that, while base objects may only give you back true or false, some derived objects can also give other values, which is why the warning you're seeing is correct.

Comment: The C code extract you linked just confirms that `a == b` can never return `NotImplemented` for any `a` and `b`. The logic of default `object` `is` comparison usage and `NotImplemeted` on false is defined [in another file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d97aef8ebfbbb275384b17f06945e583fb3189ea/Objects/typeobject.c#L5076)

Comment: Good find, @SUTerliakov. However, that appears to be only for type objects rather than all objects, which would make the linked documentation still incorrect - it seems to indicate this is done for *all* objects. I'll add your findings to the answer (and make clear that section is actually tangential to the real answer).